# LibGDX: How to put gradient color in a FreetypeFont?

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, rendering, freetype

I found a great arcade type font. I want to make a simple gradient and a one pixel width border to the font.

I managed to make a gradient from white to grey with a tool called Hiero v3.0. However Hiero saves only .fnt-files and Freetype uses ftt-files for fonts.

I managed to make a border with FreeTypeFont's setBorder-method. There's no method to create a gradient, though.

Is there a way to make a FreetypeFont with a cool gradient AND a border to use in a LibGDX game? If not, any suggestions to this situation are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with `FreeTypeFont` that much but there is no set way to do what you want that I know off. I think you have to code that for yourself.

I think you are better off using Hiero. You can:

- Create a large font and scale that down to the proper size depending on the target resolution.
- Create multiple sizes of your font and pick the one depending on the target resolution.

Sorry, not the answer you wanted. If you really want to work with `FreeTypeFont`  you might get some good tips to get started in the IRC chat where the top contributors often hang out. `rc.freenode.net` `#libgdx`. There is a [thread on the LibGDX forums](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=18157) as well where RobRendell successfully implemented gradients but it does not compile anymore with newer versions of libGDX.